# Use one Wi-Fi adapter for internet and another one for a hotspot on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, hotspot

I have a computer running Windows 10 Pro. It has two Wi-Fi adapters:

- Built-in Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160
- Linksys Compact Wireless-G USB Adapter (WUSB54GC, very old)

Both adapters work fine by themselves. I connect to the internet using the built-in adapter. I want other devices to connect to the internet via Wi-Fi through the computer. However, if I set up a hotspot normally, Windows freezes and then crashes (probably a driver issue but there are no newer drivers available). So I want Windows to use the old USB adapter for the hotspot but there seems to be no way to set it up like that.

I tried [Choose which adapter to use for mobile hotspot on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1448054/choose-which-adapter-to-use-for-mobile-hotspot-on-windows-10), but when I try to turn on the hotspot, it fails with "We can't set up mobile hotspot". I know there's a possible solution involving bridged connections, but it relies on a fixed IP address, and I don't have access to configure the router.

Does anyone know how I could accomplish this? Thanks!